# run a custom script when called with no args

Tags: bash, kubectl

. Working language is python. I want to attach a shell script when no argument is given or on own option.
Sorry if there is any confusion..
The main working flow is im working on a commmad called kubectl. So if the user enters this command without any arguments(my own option on this command) then i want to execute a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `kubectl` by a function to accomplish that. Just append the function below to your `.bashrc`.

```
kubectl()
    case $* in
    ( kadalu ) /path/to/script ;;
    ( *      ) command kubectl "$@"
    esac
```